# How to join solr documents on query time?

Tags: join, solr

I'm working with Solr 4.8.1.
I have a bunch of large documents which most fields are seldom updated.
On the other hand one of the fields on them is updated repeatedly.
I don't want to update the entire document each time the single field is changed since it will have bad impact on performance.
Is there a way to put the updated field in a different small document and then join the two for sorting and faceting queries?
I'm familiar with Atomic update and it doesn't solve the case since Solr will re-index the entire document.

Comment: why don't you want to try to use Delta import?

Comment: AFAIK delta import will require re-indexing of the entire document. @Oyeme